# Polymorphism in Python

Tags: python, methods, polymorphism

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            self.filename = filename
            self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
            self.__read()
        else:
            raise Exception('...')

    def __read(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('Abstract method')

class FileA(File):
    def __read(self):
        pass

file = FileA('myfile.a')

# NotImplementedError: Abstract method
```

My question: what's wrong? How I can fix my code to FileA use `FileA.__read()` to read the file instead of `File.__read()`? :S

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's worth noting that implementing 'abstract methods' by having the base method raise `NotImplementedError` breaks multiple inheritance. Using the [abc](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) module is a much better way to do this.

Comment: @Michael Anderson: StackOverflow maintains a complete change log.  You do not  need to post a comment indicating you made a change.  It's obvious beyond repeating.  Please delete your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefixing an attribute with double underscores doesn't make the attribute private, it simply makes polymorphism impossible because the attribute name gets mangled with the *current* class name. Change it to a single underscore prefix instead.

Comment: Better still, simply avoid all fooling around with "privacy" until you have an actual problem with someone actually corrupting your class using an attribute or method incorrectly.  Until someone **actually** misunderstands your API, do not use any privacy constructs of any kind.

Comment: Oh my! That was it. :|

I always confuse Python rules with PHP rules. Sorry for that and thank you for the answer, guys! :)

Comment: Worth noting that the under/dunder convention is useful for suggesting the difference between public methods that are going to be relatively reliable vs. private ones that may change at any moment.

Comment: The double underscore prefix isn't convention, it's syntactic sugar that results in mangling.

Answer (score 1):

You can also leave the method undefined in the base class to achieve the same effect.

```
import os
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            self.filename = filename
            self.file = open(filename, 'rb')
            self._read()
        else:
            raise Exception('...')
class FileA(File):
    def _read(self):
        pass
file = FileA('myfile.a')
```

It is invaluable to the understanding of Python classes to have this understanding of class inheritance.