# Calling an inherited property in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Polymorphism in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964929/polymorphism-in-python)

Hi
I'm trying to call a property in a class, that is inherited from my baseclass, but it doesn't work. I guess I'm missing something, but what?
Here is my  code:

```
class Produkt:
 def __init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto):
     self.__produktId = pID     #atributt for produkt nummer
     self.__produktNavn = pProdNavn #atributt for produkt navn
     self.__produktNetto = pNetto   #egenskap for nettopris

 def getName(self): #Metode for å finne produktnavnet
    return self.__produktNavn

class Bok(Produkt):
    def __init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto,pForfatter):
        Produkt.__init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto)
        self.__produktForfatter = pForfatter  #atributtp for forfatter

def getNet(self):
    return self.__produktNetto
```

as you see I'm trying to call the _productNetto property that is inherited from my Produkt class.

What am I doing wrong?

/Andy

Comment: Your indentation of getNet is incorrect.

Comment: What is happening when you try? What exactly does not work?

Answer (score 4):

It works fine if you don't use double underscore in attribute names

```
class Produkt:
 def __init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto):
     self.produktId = pID     
     self.produktNavn = pProdNavn
     self.produktNetto = pNetto   

 def getName(self): 
    return self.__produktNavn

class Bok(Produkt):
    def __init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto,pForfatter):
        Produkt.__init__(self,pID,pProdNavn,pNetto)
        self.produktForfatter = pForfatter  

    def getNet(self):
        return self.produktNetto


x = Bok(1, 2, 3, 4)
print x.getNet()
```

output:

> 3

Otherwise the names get mangled and it is looking for attribute _Bok__produktNetto. See: http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers

```
AttributeError: Bok instance has no attribute '_Bok__produktNetto'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you named those members with two leading underscores, which makes them invisible under those names outside that class (see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

If you rename those fields with a single underscore in both places, it will work as you intend.